# Localized GKTurnBasedMatch message

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

The message property of GKTurnBasedMatch allows changing the text in the push notification that the next participant receives, but how can I localize it? I tried using Localizable.strings but that doesn't work. I know that regular push notification can easily be localized, but since Game Center has full control over these notifications it seems impossible to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with the same problem a few months back.

I ended creating a user class with information about which localization the user was preferring, and then let the other player decide language.

something like:

- player1: Starts game
- player1: inform player2 about nickname, preferred lang etc
- player2: inform player1 about nickname, preferred
  lang etc.
- player1: send message to player2 in preferred lang.

Not really elegant but working.